# How to make a function inside another function quit both functions at once?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I'm making a program that asks the users some questions and uses different functions to react to what the user gives as input. I need to make it such that if the user ever types "Cancel", it will not only end the function they are currently in but even the function that called the prior function.

```
def func1(x):
    func2(x+5)
    print 5
def func2(x):
    func3(x+5)
    print 5
def func3(x):
    print x
    return

func1(20)
print 10

# 30
# 5
# 5
# 10
```

So currently this will print 30, exit func3, print 5, exit func2, print 5, exit func1. I need a way for it to just stop after func3 prints 30. Any ideas?

So the desired output would be.

```
#30
#10
```

Edit: This is an extremely simplified version, they wouldn't type cancel in this specific code. It would be in a `raw_input`.

Comment: Throw an exception and catch it?

Comment: How will the use 'type' cancel?

Comment: *"they are currently in"*: what does it mean that a user is *in* a function? That does not make sense to me. Why not give the example with the code for the input you speak of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raising an `exception` quits the function stack just like the way you are describing. So you can have the outermost function `try-expect` all the inner functions. If any of the inner function raises an `exception`, it will bubble up (i.e it won't execute any of the subsequent code in the stack) until it reaches the outermost function's `except`.

```
def func1(x):
    try:
      func2(x+5)
      print 5
    except:
      pass  

def func2(x):
    func3(x+5)
    print 5

def func3(x):
    print x
    raise("Foo")  # user's input should drive this.
    return

func1(20)
print 10
```

It reaches till `func3` in a normal way. `func3` however says it doesn't want the normal execution flow to `func2` which cascades it to `func1`.

If you don't want to change the function's content you can use the following decorator. It also has the corrections mentioned in the comments.

```
class UserAbort(Exception):
    pass

def swallow(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        try:
            f(*args)
        except UserAbort:
            pass
    return wrapper

@swallow
def func1(x):
    func2(x+5)
    print 5

def func2(x):
    func3(x+5)
    print 5

def func3(x):
    print x
    raise UserAbort  # user's input should drive this.
    return

func1(20)
print 10
```

Comment: Are you sure `raise("Foo")` is valid Python?

Comment: `raise` is not a function but a statement and should be invoked as `raise Exception()` - it only works in your example because `(...)` is perceived as a grouping statement. Also, capturing all exceptions with a plain `except` is a bad practice as it will capture keyboard interrupts and other system/unintended exceptions that in most cases you do not want to capture like this.

Comment: @zwer. To add on, I was going to suggest defining a custom label type like `class UserPressedCancel(Exception): pass` this would avoid any complications caused by catching unintended exception types.

Comment: Thanks. Syntax error's that didn't seem obvious to me!